# IN MySQL SELECT Query IF Value not Found in Table Return 0 ELSE return the value

Tags: mysql, if-statement

My question i need Mysql Query if there is no value found in any table then i want to return the result value to zero else the value which i found.

i tried out every solution every solution which is provided by ChatGPT but i am failed to get my specific result

i tried out,

```
SELECT IF( EXISTS( SELECT RepairingId FROM expenses where WorkDate='2023-07-23 00:00:00' and VehRegNo='PB-56B-8508'), 1, 0) AS RepairId;` -- this is working but i want the value of RepairingId not just 1
         
SELECT IFNULL(RepairingId, 0) AS result FROM expenses where WorkDate='2023-07-24 00:00:00' and VehRegNo='PB-56B-8508';` -- this give me no value

SELECT CASE WHEN RepairingId IS NOT NULL THEN RepairingId ELSE 0 END AS resultFROM expenses where WorkDate='2023-07-24 00:00:00' and VehRegNo='PB-56B-8508'; -- this give me no value
```

Comment: Why don't you rely on yourself instead of ChatGPT?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT IFNULL((SELECT RepairingId FROM expenses WHERE WorkDate='2023-07-23 00:00:00' AND VehRegNo='PB-56B-8508'), 0) AS RepairId;
```

or

```
SELECT IFNULL(RepairingId, 0) AS result FROM expenses WHERE WorkDate='2023-07-24 00:00:00' AND VehRegNo='PB-56B-8508' LIMIT 1;
```

or

```
SELECT CASE WHEN RepairingId IS NOT NULL THEN RepairingId ELSE 0 END AS result FROM expenses WHERE WorkDate='2023-07-24 00:00:00' AND VehRegNo='PB-56B-8508' LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(
    (SELECT RepairingId FROM expenses WHERE WorkDate='2023-07-24 00:00:00' AND VehRegNo='PB-56B-8508' LIMIT 1),
    0
) AS result;
```

You can see my example in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cQ3Ds_La)